# How to use two ng-modal in one input type in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using angular js. And implementing input checkbox, So this checkbox checked by default from angular controller using ng-model:

**Controller:**

```
var checkBoxVal = true;
  $scope.checkboxModel = {
    value : checkBoxVal,
  } 

$scope.call = function(){
alert("--comes--");
 if($scope.checkboxModel== false)
  {

  }
  if($scope.mycheckbox== true){

  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value" data-ng-change="call();"/>
```

But when call the function "call()" then it is not coming in if condition because **$scope.checkboxModel** is undefined.
When I use only **ng-model="checkboxModel"** then it is coming in if condition with true and false. But I want to use both set true value in like ng-**model="checkboxModel.value"** and compare the checkbox value after calling the call() function.

Comment: Change like this if($scope.checkboxModel.value)

Comment: @Vivz It is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two ng-models. Change your condition to this since you want to evaluate based on ng-models value

`if($scope.checkboxModel.value`)